# new gapi($ga_email,$ga_password) thows fatal error now

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I had this code working for years, I used to retrieve google analytics data

```
$ga_email       = 'my@gmail.com';
$ga_password    = 'myp@ss';
$ga_profile_id  = '40871339';
$ga_url         =  urldecode($_GET['url']);
$ga_id         =  urldecode($_GET['id']);
$ga_start         =  substr(urldecode($_GET['fecha']),0, 10);
$ajustado = false;
$customRange = 'date';
if( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($ga_start)) < date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-09-10") )){
    $ajustado = true;
    $ga_start = '2013-09-10';
}
/*
if ( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($ga_start)) < date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-100 day", time()))){
    $customRange = 'week';
}
*/
if($ga_url == '')
    $ga_url = '/';

/* Create a new Google Analytics request and pull the results */
try {
    $ga = new gapi($ga_email,$ga_password);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<h2 style="margin-top: 50px; color: #922">Hubo un error inesperado. Por favor, intentalo más tarde..</h2>';
    die();
}
```

But I realised that throws a fatal error now

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Error: "https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps "' in /var/www/html/gapi.class.php:419 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/gapi.class.php(63): gapi->authenticateUser('my@gmail.c...', 'myp@a..') #1 /var/www/html/includes/gareport.php(93): gapi->__construct('my@gmail.c...', 'myp@a..') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/gapi.class.php on line 419
```

And That a correct email/password,

Did this stop working?

Comment: *Important: ClientLogin has been [officially deprecated](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps) since April 20, 2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) as soon as possible.*

Comment: But this was working at least 2 months a go... Did google maintain it for a bit longer, I guess..

Comment: it was a rolling shutdown they didn't shut it down for everything at the same time.